# Ubuntu Linux Filepath for Windows mounted drive

Tags: command-line, nautilus

I'm using ubuntu desktop.  I mounted a windows drive using the "connect to a server" option.  It now shows up in the "Network" list right above "Browse network".  I'm trying to cd to this folder in the terminal and cannot seem to figure out what the correct file path is.  When I go to the properties of the folder, it shows the location as "smb://engserver/engineering/".  However if I cd
`cd smb://engserver/engineering/` it says there is no such file or directory.  How do I access this folder via cd?

Comment: check `/media`, it should show up there

Comment: cd /media/engserver brings up nothing.  Also if I cd /media and press Tab to show the contents, it is not there either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Samba mounts via the Gnome desktop (Nautilus) are mounted per user in the directory

```
/home/user/.gvfs/
```

Just change `user` to your user name or use `~/.gvfs/` instead.

If you have the samba tools installed, you can mount that samba share in a more general (not per-user) fashion wherever you want (e. g. via `/etc/fstab`).  Maybe that is more what you want?

Comment: Thanks, I ended up having to use `cd ~/.gvfs/engineering\ on\ engserver/`  Not sure why the wording is backwards but it works so I'm happy.

Comment: The wording is probably because this way it is shorter in English.  `~/.gvfs/engserver\ exporting\ engineering/` would be the original word order.  Maybe there's a better solution they just couldn't think of.

Comment: no such a directory